# How is confidence interval related to central limit theorem?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, inference, central-limit-theorem

I am currently looking into Confidence Interval and sees that Confidence Interval is possible based on Central Limit Theorem. So, I have been looking for how Central Limit Theorem is related to Confidence Interval but I can only understand part by part meaning I can understand Central Limit Theorem and I can also understand Confidence Interval. However, I don't understand how they are related to each other(For example, how things are translated to 'z').

I'd like to understand how Central Limit Theorem is applied to Confidence Interval and hope to understand specific elements related from Central Limit Theorem to Confidence Interval.

Comment: Afaik, they are not inherently related. For a finite sample, CLT can be used to *approximate* the distribution of the (test) statistic and thereby construct an *approximate* confidence interval at a given level of significance.

Answer (score 1):

Several frequently used styles of confidence intervals, especially CIs that are intended for use with large samples, happen to be based on the central limit theorem. But many confidence intervals have no particular relationship to the CLT.

**CIs for binomial proportion.** The Wald CI for the Success probability $p$ of a binomial model is based on the normal approximation to a normal distribution. That approximation relies on the CLT. If you get $X$ successes in $n$ trials, then a 95% Wald CI for $p$ is of the form $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$ where $\hat p = X/n.$

*Example:* (Computation in R.)

```
set.seed(1234)
n = 1000;  p = .3        # large n
x = rbinom(1, n, p)
p.hat = x/n
p.hat + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)
[1] 0.2589629 0.3150371  # CI contains .3
```

This interval is based on the fact that $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n,p)$
also has $\frac{X - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$
As long as $n$ is as large as 1000, this interval works very well. For smaller $n$ it is better  to use the estimate $\tilde p = (X+2)/(n+4)$ and the 95% Agresti-Coull CI $\tilde p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\tilde p(1-\tilde p)}{n+4}}.$

*Example:*

```
set.seed(1235)
n = 10; p = .7           # small n
x = rbinom(1, n, p)
p.est = (x+2)/(n+4)
p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/(n+4))
[1] 0.4776469 0.9509246  # CI contains 0.7
```

**CI for normal mean.** A 95% confidence interval for normal mean $\mu$ is of the form
$\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$ where $\pm t^*$ cut probability $0.025$ from the upper and lower tails, respectively, of Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, where $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are mean and variance of a normal sample. If data are normal, this interval works well for small and large $n,$
[Sometimes people bring up arguments involving the CLT to excuse using this interval when it does not really apply, but this
interval is not fundamentally based on the CLT.}

*Example:*

```
set.seed(1236)
mu = 100;  sg = 15;  n = 20
x = rnorm(n, mu, sg)
a = mean(x);  s = sd(x)
a + qt(c(.025,.975), n-1)*s/sqrt(n)
[1]  94.22909 107.90066  # CI contains 100

t.test(x)$conf.int
[1]  94.22909 107.90066
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

**CI for normal variance.** Also, a commonly used 95% CI for the normal variance $\sigma^2$ is of
the form $\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U}, \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right),$ where
$L$ and $U$ cut probability $0.025$ from the lower and upper tails, respectively, of the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=n-1).$ This interval is for normal data, but does not rely on the CLT, and it works for both small and large $n.$

*Example (continued):*

```
(n-1)*s^2/qchisq(c(.975,.025), n-1)
[1] 123.3803 455.0971  # CI contains 15^2 = 225
```